# Dividing $N$ into $n$ groups such that a specific pair is a member of at least one group.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

$N$ is a set, $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_r,x,y\}$ and has to be divided into $n$ groups, such that one of the groups has both $x$ and $y$. How do I find the number of ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Think of a new set
$$
\tilde{N}=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_r,xy\},
$$
in which we have combined $x$ and $y$ in to a single symbol.  How are divisions of $\tilde{N}$ in to $n$ groups related to division of $N$ in to $n$ groups where $x$ and $y$ are in the same part?

Comment: Thank you, but being new to the topic, I don't quite understand what you mean. So, I would like it if you could explain it to me in a simpler way.

Comment: We're using the new symbol "$xy$" as a marker -- whichever part of your partition it lands in gets _both $x$ and $y$_.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question. Let us say there are 20 children playing a game. They divide themselves into 4 groups. Two children make a deal to stay in the same team. In how many ways can they achieve this?

Comment: @user124740 That doesn't change my answer: consider those two children as a single entity when you are splitting up in to groups.  So you have $19$ "entities" to split up in to $4$ groups, with no restrictions; how many ways can you do this?

Comment: Ok, I get it know, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nicholas R. Peterson answered it spot on. I'm not sure I have enough room to expand on his answer in the comments, so I'll append an answer to hopefully help you visualize better.

Consider the children:
John
Julie
Bob
Alice
Eve

Alice and Bob make a deal to stay in the same group. So rather than permuting five children, we want to permute John, Julie, Eve, {Alice and Bob}. In this sense, we treat Alice and Bob as a "cluster" or group. Equivocally, how would you divide John, Julie, Eve, and Alice into subgroups, ignoring Bob? At the end, you stick Bob into Alice's group.

Does this make more sense?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!